# Stack reverse matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, stack, reverse

I am trying to make stack by matrix and reverse stack matrix and show it  like sit in a box:

```
stack=[]
x=int(input("Enter size of stack :"))
Top=-1
for i in range(x):
    Top+=1
    stack.append(int(input("Top is in {} position\nEnter stack item  :".format(i))))
print("stack=",stack)
print("|",stack[Top],"|","==>Top")
for i in range(len(stack)-1):
    Top-=1
    print("|",stack[Top],"|")

rev=[]
rev_top=-1
for x in range(-1,-len(stack)-1,-1):
    rev.append(stack[x])
    rev_top+=1
print("stack recerse =",rev)
```

The put:

```
|7 4 5 |==>Top
|3 5 9 |
|2 4 5 |
|4 5 2 |
```

I want it's reverse be like this

```
|4 5 2 | ==>Top
|2 4 5 |
|3 5 9 |
|7 4 5 |
```

So each time I pop row the top position moves to the next of it until stack Empty.

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of your relatively long code for reversing elements in the `stack` list

```
rev=[]
rev_top=-1
for x in range(-1,-len(stack)-1,-1):
    rev.append(stack[x])
    rev_top+=1
```

you may use built-in function `reversed()`:

```
rev = list(reversed(stack))         # list() is used because reversed() returns an iterator
```

or - even better - reverse the `stack` list in place with the `reverse()` method:

```
stack.reverse()  # Note: Do NOT use something as stack = stack.reverse() - you will get Null
```

Now you may use the same code from your program to nice print the reversed stack, i. e. the part

```
top = -1
print("|", stack[top], "|", "==>Top")
for i in range(len(stack) - 1):
    top -= 1
    print("|", stack[top], "|")
```

(I put some space symbols to it and changed the variable name `Top` to `top` to be in the concordance with [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).)

Comment: I know I can use method reverse but I don't want to use it

Comment: Because of ...?

Comment: Why don´t perform smarter exercises than implement build-in functions in so poor way? Why ask a question if answers don't interest you?